# Can we log per spring Integration flow?

Tags: spring, logging, spring-integration

Spring integration really helps us a lot during application integration, it make us more focus on flow design.

However we have an requirement to have logs per integration flow, any suggestions how to achieve this? Currently we use `<int:message-history/>` for logging.

in our case, each integration flow is one spring-context.xml, and we load one spring-context.xml with a separated `ApplicationContext`, actually we want each `ApplicationContext` has its own log file, this will greatly help us for issue tracking

As we have many integration flows, so currently all logs are in one log file, so it is not easy for us to find the log we want, and it is difficult for us to trace the message history.

Thanks.